# Definition of function which is the class member

Tags: c++, function, class, private, member

I have two functions, which are private members of class "Data":

```
class Date
{
private:
    bool leapYear(int y);
    void fillDate(int d, Month m, int y);
};
```

So, where is the best to define this functions:

- in class definition;
- in header file outside the class;
- or in ".cpp" file?

Comment: All of these methods have their pro's and cons. It depends. And you forgot to list the [Pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) as a 4th alternative.

Comment: I would typically implement in the cpp file, as I find this the place I would normally refer to when looking for a function implementation, but really I think it might come down to preference/convention. If you were working as a team on a project, then it would be best to stick to a well defined rule for this concept.

Comment: Use option 1 or option 3, both are good in this situation. The important thing is to stay consistent about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the choice here. Here are some ideas to make your mind:

- Inlining for speed is no longer a concern, since compilers are now good at link time optimization. So performance should not be a decision factor here (compilation speed matters too, but this is another bag of worms).
- Small inline member functions, defined inside the class, may be an easy way to "document" what the class does. Also, this tends to keep the implementation localized, which is comfortable when reading the code. Don't overdo it however.
- Large functions should in principle go into their own file, or at least outside the class definition, since they clutter the class definition code for no good reason. Template code is no exception.
- Pimpl have advantages/disadvantages too, but here I don't see any good reason to introduce such beasts in your simple case. They are used typically to reduce dependencies between header files.

Here, if the implementation is small, you can write the code inline, inside the class. But you should put them in their own implementation (".cpp") file, if the logic is complex.

You can also start inline, and when the code has settled to something more complex, move the implementation to its own file.

Comment: So, this ideas suit private member functions too?

Comment: @FireCrosser: Yes, and also non-member functions and operators.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly discourage you to consider option 2. This gets you "Multiple definition" error by the linker if you include this file in more than one implementation file, because the definition will be copied (by the preprocessor) to each .cpp file.

Comment: You can use the `inline` keyword to tell the linker not to be confused.

Answer (score 0):

My personal philosophy about this is to put all function definitions into the implementation (.cpp) file, because, first of all, it separates declarations (+ documentation) from definitions which adds to code clarity IMO, and, secondly, having all definitions in one place (the implementation file) makes it easier for me to find functions. In my experience it was always quite a nuisance to have to switch between header and implementation files to see whether this particular function I'm looking for was inlined / defined in the header or if it was in the implementation file. Having all function definitions in the implementation file means I know I will find the definition of *any* function in that file, and won't have to waste time switching and looking around.

Comment: I agree with you, but I need to solve just this problem - where I should place definition of the **member** and, the most important, **private** function?

Comment: Well ... in the cpp file? You can define private member functions in implementation files just as you can public ones.